# How can i sync a table between two MySQL RDS insatance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

I am trying to sync one table in two of mysql RDS instances
in AWS something like a db link or FEDERATED engine.

Comment: When you say sync table, are you talking about a one way change replication, or something that's bidirectional?